# How to prepare a closed sourced SDK module on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, obfuscation, r.java-file

### Background

I'm working on an app that has become very popular, so much that a part of it is supposed to become an SDK (which would be available for developers), and the app will split to 2 apps (both use the SDK).

According to what I know, there are multiple ways to create an SDK module (previously called "project" on Eclipse) :

1. Completely open sourced (Android library) - all sources and resources are open sourced and can be modified. An example might be Facebook's SDK and a lot of Github repos.
2. a single Jar file, which can be closed sourced.

### The problem

Sadly, I can't make the SDK open sourced, and it should relatively be protected vs prying eyes (obfuscated etc...).

The issue here is, the SDK needs to use some resources of its own (drawables, strings,...), and so far (because I didn't have a lot of experience with creating SDKs) I've found 2 ways to handle resources for SDKs :

1. use reflection and/or "context.getResources().getIdentifier" . This is quite messy, as I lose the whole "R" usage of the code. Also, it has issues with "styleable" , as I've written [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30171299/878126). It also makes it hard to find unused resources.
2. even worse ways: put resources in assets folder, put files in a wacky way inside the jar file, ...

Note that a part of the SDK includes custom views (for example, classes that extend from TextView), so even if I do split the SDk into 2 modules- resources and java files, both might have issues of dependencies (each uses the other one).

### The question

Is it possible to somehow solve this issue?

Is it possible for the code part of the SDK to remain closed sourced, reach the "R" file as usual, and make it easy for both me and whoever use the SDK ?

How would I then generate the jar file as being obfuscated via Android Studio? and is it possible to prepare it to to be used via gradle afterwards?

Can I maybe make the Android-library of the SDK into an obfuscated jar file and not worry about the "R" file ? I ask this because this way I could enjoy both worlds: for our apps, it would remain open sourced, and for third party apps it would be closed sourced.

---

EDIT: seeing that this is supposed to be easy, I've tried it myself. I've created a totally new POC project which has an Android library module called "sdkmodule", and added this class to it:

```
public class SdkClass
      {
      public String doIt(Context context)
        {
        return context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        }
      }
```

Then, I've made the app's module to use this one, and I wrote this code in it:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SdkClass sdkClass=new SdkClass();
    Log.d("AppLog","string from SDK:"+sdkClass.doIt(this));
    Log.d("AppLog","string with same ID name from app:"+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    }
```

What I expected is that the first log would print the string that's in the SDK module, and the second to show the string of the current project, but instead I got an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/user/sdkmodule/R$string;
```

On another try, I've got the same string that's used on the app itself (the one that uses the SDK module). And, on another run, the SDK produced the needed string as I've wanted.

How could it be? What should I do ?

In addition, I've tried to make a second activity in the SDK itself, and I've created a resource there that has the same resource name (used for a textView in its layout) as of the app itself, yet with a different value, yet when I've reached this activity, I've seen the one used by the app.

Here's the project, zipped (ignore the name of the folder, I wanted to try flavors too) :

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-PZZGk2vPohX25WUDNKTmotUTg/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: The AAR format for Android library projects has been available for use with Android Studio and Gradle for Android for a year-plus. Maven users can also use AARs directly. For Eclipse/Ant, unpacking an AAR into a library project (with a compiled JAR instead of source code) is not that hard, at least for basic stuff ([here's a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) that explains the process). The Play Services SDK is shipped in this basic fashion, with compiled Java bytecode instead of source code.

Comment: Suppose I have a working app, which one of its modules should be an SDK (or 2 modules if you wish - one for resources and one for source code), what should be the next steps? The website you've given is for Eclipse, and it's for using the AAR and not preparing it (though it is also important to know how to use it too).

Comment: "The website you've given is for Eclipse, and it's for using the AAR and not preparing it" -- that is why it is in parentheses at the end of a sentence discussing using an AAR in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android Archive (AAR) format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) does what you want. It's like an Android-specific JAR file and contains compiled code, but includes its own resources and manifest. You can also include obfuscation as part of the build process. By default, the current version of Android Studio (1.2) and Gradle automatically build .AAR files for all library modules you create in your project.

You can change an app module into a library project that will publish an AAR file just by changing `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` into `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in your module's Gradle file. The .AAR file will be placed in your `MODULENAME/build/outputs/aar` folder after each build. Some [more information is available here](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/building-an-aar-library-in-android-studio/).

**Edit 1, after question updated:**

The resources in your AAR get consolidated with the app module when the final APK gets compiled. The app resources will override the library's. This is probably by design, to allow people using a 3rd party library to customize its resources when creating their app, without having to rebuild the library. I think the easiest way to solve your resource conflict issue would just be to name your sdkmodule resources something more unique. Why not make the string key `R.string.com_example_sdk_name` or something?

No, the AAR libraries don't get obfuscated by default, but you can [set up ProGuard in the Gradle build file](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) for your AAR library to take care of this. Other tools are also available.

Comment: Does the generated "sdkmodule-release.aar" actually get obfuscated by default? Also, how come I can't use (even in the SDK module itself) the resources that were defined in the SDK module, and they get overridden by the app's module itself? I've updated the question.

Comment: How come on the code that reaches the SDK it succeeded getting the string resource of the SDK, while when I used the layout file and on the activity itself (added code after uploading) it got the overridden string resource ? Is it possible to avoid "spamming" whoever uses the SDK with the resources of the SDK inside the R.java file?

Comment: Also, about proguard, all I do is just add those lines, and the SDK module will get obfuscated ? if so, what would trigger it to be obfuscated ? Would it be "generate signed APK" ? or something else? Or, as I think (according to what's written), I can make a new flavor that will do just that and nothing more ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper My understanding is that adding those lines to your Gradle file will cause Proguard to run on any release build. So "Generate Signed APK", "Assembly Release" from the Gradle Tasks menu, etc. If you have further questions about ProGuard though I'd suggest asking them as a separate SO question, since this question is pretty broad already and I'm not an expert on ProGuard.

Comment: I see, can you please answer about the resource-"spamming" issue? and if it's possible to avoid overriding resources without making very unique resource names?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - My own experimentation suggests that any resources in your library will get included in any app and APK that is built with it, which makes sense. I haven't been able to find any way to avoid overriding resources without a unique name, but I've found very little documentation about this.

Comment: OK, thank you for all your help. This is a very nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your problem is to package and distribute your library as an [AAR bundle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format)

This format allows you to provide an obfuscated SDK jar and with its resources and the R mapping file.

This format is a standard and fully supported by [maven-android-plugin](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/) (actually it's the replacement of the old APKLib format which supports only the distribution of source files).

Of course it's also supported by Gradle and Android Studio.

Comment: Question is, can I still use R as usual, and is there a nice tutorial about how to use it? people at the office already made the AAR and put it on gradle, but they've made the R file unused and use "getIdentifier" everywhere. I think it's a bad thing to do, but I couldn't find a proper tutorial for this, plus have no experience with AAR related topics and last time I made an SDK was a very long time ago, using Eclipse.

Comment: Let's say I have a working app, which one of its modules should be an SDK (or 2 modules if you wish - one for resources and one for source code), what should be the next steps?

Comment: You have to explicitly say to the app that use the SDK to depend to a library. At compile time, both R files will be merged and everything will work perfectly. If you want to provide a SDK with resources and obfuscated source code you don't need to have to different modules. One is enough.  I don't have time to create a tutorial since I'm currently releasing a project but let me check if I find something interesting. Do you use Gradle or Maven (or unfortunately none of them)?

Comment: @androiddeveloper You really don't need to do anything special inside of the library. It has a res folder and automatically generates an R class that you can use in your library just as your used to. The compiler takes care of merging the resources when you compile your final APK.

Comment: @joshua-carmody gave a good tutorial for Android Studio in its response. If you're using Maven (it's recommended to use the last released version), you just need to change the packaging format to aar instead of apk and it will create the AAR module directly.

Comment: ok, I've tried to make something as I see you say it's very easy, but it crashes. Please see the updated question